# Wine up-charges

Tags: catalog, catalog-price-rules

We ship wine to specific states and we need to add a $7 Adult verification to all orders. Is there a way to add this fee to the shopping cart or to the product pages so the customer know on top of the cost and tax that there is a $7 fee.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use cart rules that apply negatice (-) discounts.

[Here](http://magentoshweta.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-negative-discount-amount-in.html) is a step by step on setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can create a module, you could add a custom total to the cart. (Please replace colin_core and Colin_Core with your own module name)

So in your config.xml file you would register the total:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <wine_charge>
                        <class>colin_core/totals_wine_charge</class>
                        <after>subtotal,shipping</after>
                        <before>tax</before>
                    </wine_charge>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then under Model/Totals/Wine directory you would add the following class:

```
<?php

class Colin_Core_Model_Totals_Wine_Charge
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{

    public function getWineCharge()
    {
        // Can replace with a config option
        return 7;
    }

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);
        if (($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping')) {
            return $this;
        }


        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
        $charge = $store->convertPrice($this->getWineCharge());
        $address->setWineChargeAmount($charge);
        $address->setWineChargeBaseAmount($charge);
        $this->_addAmount($charge);
        $this->_addBaseAmount($charge);

        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $charge = $address->getWineChargeAmount();
        if ($charge == 0) {
            return $address;
        }

        $address->addTotal(
            array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => Mage::helper('colin_core')->__('Additional Wine Charge'),
                'value' => $charge
            )
        );
        return $address;
    }
}
```

When you go to the checkout you see something similar to the image below

[image]